Find the Laurent series $e^{2z} + \cos \frac{2}{z}$ in the domain $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$.
Find the Laurent series $e^{2z} + \cos \frac{2}{z}$ in the domain $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$.

I just want to make sure I'm doing this right. We clearly have
\begin{align}
    \begin{split}
        e^{2z} &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(2z)^n}{n!} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2^n}{n!} z^n
    \end{split}
\end{align}
But then we clearly also have
\begin{align}
    \begin{split}
        \cos\left( \frac{2}{z} \right) &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{2n}\left( \frac{2}{z}\right)^{2n}}{n!} \\
        &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-2)^{2n}}{n!}z^{-2n} \\
    \end{split}
\end{align}
Hence,
\begin{align}
    \begin{split}
        e^{2z} + \cos \frac{2}{z} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2^n}{n!} z^n + \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-2)^{2n}}{n!}z^{-2n}
    \end{split}
\end{align}
Does this look alright?

The series of $\cos$ should be $(-1)^n$, otherwise $(-2)^{2n}$ is just $2^{2n}$.

@AngaeMT oh my goodness thank you for pointing out this silly error. I bet I could rewrite it so that we have $(-1)^n 2^{2n} = (-1)^n (4^n) = (-4)^n$
